# Multiple functions in onclick in Aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, modal

I have one button "new case", and when clicking on it, it is opening one link and subtab. So I have 2 functions: one for link(linkbutton) and one for subtab(newsubtab). How do i use both functions in one click?

So that when clicking on "new case" it opens the link as well as the subtab?

How do I merge below code?

#Salesforce Developer #aura #Lightning

//for link

```html
<aura:if istrue="{v.test}">

    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem style="" label="new case" onclick='{c.linkbutton}'/>

    <aura:set attribute="else">

        <form name="testform" aura:id="abs" target="" method="Post">

            <a id:"testlink" onclick='{c.linkbutton}'> new case </a>

        </form>

    </aura:set>

</aura:if>
```

// for subtab

```html
<aura:if  istrue="{v.test}">

    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem style="" label="new case" name="new case" onclick='{c.newsubtab}'/>

    <aura:set attribute="else">

        <a id:"new case" title="new case"  onclick='{c.newsubtab}'> new case </a>

    </aura:set>

</aura:if>
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code you have to your question. I don't see how this can be answered without understanding your markup.

Comment: Actually it's related to my work , so I can't share code because of privacy concerns and idk how do i explain it

Comment: Most of us here have signed a work contract or separate paper obliging to strict confidentiality. Preparing a good StackExchange question means to reduce something complex to its important bits; according to my experience not much an employer can complain about is left at this point, but you should do some final clean up, remove session IDs etc. As for intellectual property, not much here is on a level with, say, [Martin Hairer's products](https://hairersoft.com/) anyway. (I'm just an admirer, unaffiliated.)

Comment: okay , i have updated my question with code, kindky help me

Comment: Nisha, I've stared at your question some time and frankly don't get it. In Aura, when you have two Javascript functions doing the same, you do this by having a single function in the helper file that is called by both functions. So much regarding how to "merge" two Javascript functions in Aura. But when I look at your markup - you display the `verticalNavigationItem` on the condition of `test` being true. If not true, you display a link (with some "id:..." - no idea what you mean to do with the colon after `id`). What is the idea of this condition? If unrelated to your question, remove it.